# If $f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ is Riemann-Integrable on every closed subinterval of $(0,1]$, Is it possible that $f$ is not Lebesgue-Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

> If $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ is Riemann-Integrable on every closed subinterval of $(0,1]$, Is it possible that $f$ is not Lebesgue-Integrable ?

According to a lemma(which has to be proven):

$f$ is Lebesgue-Integrable $\Leftrightarrow \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\int_\epsilon^1f(x)\, dx$ exists in $\mathbb R$

then we have to assume that the limit doesn't exist, but is this not a contradiciton to the Riemann-Integrability ?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: The Riemann integral is *not* defined for intervals of infinite length.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not a contradiction. That limit existing means that the *improper* Riemann integral exists. Take for example $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$.

$f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ (it is not bounded), but it is improperly Riemann integrable in the sense that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_\epsilon^1 f(x) dx$ exists (and therefore by your Lemma also Lebesgue integrable).

Regarding your initial statement: Yes it is possible, just give $f$ a non-integrable singularity at $0$, for example, $f(x)=1/x^2$ works. It is Riemann integrable on all finite closed subintervals of $(\epsilon, \infty)$ but not Lebesgue integrable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another example:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\sin\frac{1}{x},\qquad x \in (0,1]
$$
Certainly $f$ is Riemenn integrable on $[a,1]$ for any $a>0$.  But
$$
\int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx = +\infty
$$
so $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

**added**

Even better
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x},\qquad x \in (0,1]
$$
Now the improper Riemann integral converges, but the Lebesgue integral still does not exist.  This is essentially the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/n$ converges conditionally but not absolutely.